# Set loop in function to create Row values based on previous row value

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

```
Test3 <- function(n,d) {
  
  die1 = sample(1:d, n, replace = TRUE)
  die2 = sample(1:d, n, replace = TRUE)
  move = die1 + die2
  position_before_roll = move
  position_after_roll = move
  
 
  monopoly_sim = data.frame(position_before_roll, die1,die2,move,position_after_roll)
  monopoly_sim[1,1]=0
  
  

  #Needs to be position after roll + Dice Roll (Move)
  monopoly_sim[n+1,1] = monopoly_sim[n,5] 
  
  
  
  return(monopoly_sim)

  }


df = Test3(5,6)
x1= as.data.frame(df)
```

Here is my code. I am attempting to make my `position_before_roll = to my previous position_after_roll`.

From there have `position_after_roll = position_before_roll + move`.

I am not able to get the rows updated. Only the last row is updated because it has the n+1 value (`n=5` in this case)

Comment: position_after_roll is a variable and you're treating it as a 2d array; so there would be incorrect dimensions.

Comment: How should I proceed from here to change it accordingly?

Comment: i don't get the logic in the for loop. can you elaborate? also, whatever you do in the for loop will not alter monopoly_sim; so the loop is redundant.

Comment: Do you think I can make the data frame without a loop simply putting n-1 as the entries?

I think i see your point with the loop.

I do not know how to make it so that the column I want is equal to the previous column

Comment: you don't need the loop. once you build your dataframe, then you can shift the column values as needed.

Comment: pls edit your question with you new code. hard to read it in the comments

Comment: I need this to be a functional form in which i can create a database with n being 1000 if i wanted. I dont understand what you mean by shifting the column values as needed. That seems like a massive hassle. It really feels like there is a way to do this easily with for loop.

Comment: try using data.table instead and [parallelize](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/) your code

Comment: I figured it out with a forloop. Thanks for the time.